# Zero-inflated negative binomial distribution

Tags: distribution

I need to generate 1000 sample (each with 30 observations) from Zero Inflated Negative binomial distribution. We are supposed to choose our own parameters to do so. But I can't find any guide to what reasonable values for parameters are (dispersion for example, mu etc); Some places say mu should be 0<mu<1, while some give examples with higher mu. How large theta is in zero-inlfated distribution?
[image]
Any advice? Is there another R function can also be used for this?

rzinbinom(30, mu, theta, size, pi).
x-vector of (non-negative integer) quantiles.
q-vector of quantiles.
p-vector of probabilities.
n-number of random values to return (30 in our case)
mu-vector of non-negative means of the uninflated negative binomial distribution.
theta, size-vector of strictly positive dispersion parameters (shape parameter of the gamma mixing distribution).